# SQL script for splitting a string into rows containing one character each?

Tags: oracle10g

How can a word like 'ORACLE' be displayed as rows like this, using only one SQL statement?

**Word**

O

R

A

C

L

E

Answer (score 3):

You could use the CONNECT BY condition:

```
SELECT SUBSTR('ORACLE', level, 1)
FROM dual
CONNECT BY level <= LENGTH('ORACLE');
```

*Edit 1*: As per Alex Poole's suggestion, I replaced `regexp_substr('ORACLE', '.', 1, level) IS NOT NULL` with `level <= LENGTH('ORACLE');`

*Edit 2*: I replaced `regexp_substr` with `substr`

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/25347)

Comment: I have gone through couple of other ways of hierarchical querying also... Seems these iterations can be done with CONNECT BY only...

Any suggestion on whether it can be done with decode?

Comment: You could do it with `decode` as well, but you would still have to use `CONNECT BY`. But you could also do it with `SUBSTR` (without the need of `regexp`). See my updated answer.

Comment: Got an another way which can be used in any version of ORACLE..

    SELECT substr('ORACLE', rownum, 1) FROM all_objects WHERE rownum <= (SELECT length('ORACLE') FROM dual)

Comment: Yes, but this will not work if there are less than 6 objects; still, it's an alternative for older versions.